# Does Magento Enterprise still use url_path product attribute?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, entity-attribute-value

I am comparing Magento Community and Enterprise editions. When a new product is created under Community, the value of product attribute `url_path` (`attribute_id` = 98) is getting saved correctly in the table `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.

However, when the same product is created under Enterprise, this attribute value does not appear to being getting saved. I am not seeing any values in the table `catalog_product_entity_varchar` for the `url_path` attribute.

Is there any difference between how Community and Enterprise treat the `url_path` attribute? Does Enterprise edition actually make use of the `url_path` value somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, around Enterprise version 1.12 or 1.13 Magento changed the way it handles `url_key` attribute for product and category. It got its own table `catalog_product_entity_url_key` and both products and categories requires `url_key` attribute to be unique in the store. This was done due to changes in url rewrite process which are not saved in `core_url_rewrite` but in `enterprise_url_rewrite*` tables and the new indexing which is mostly automatic and run by cron according to states in `enterprise_mview_*` tables.

Comment: thanks for your replies. Instead of url_key, actually I would like to be interesting about url_path attribute.